# For every infinite set A there exists infinite B,C such that A=B∪C

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

> Prove for every set $A$, there exists sets $B,C$ such that $A=B∪C$,
> $B∩C=∅$ and $|A|=|B|=|C|$ when
>
> a. $|A|=ℵ_{0}$
>
> b. $|A|=ℵ$

I'm really not sure of my proof, especially in the part I say A\A' is also infinite.. and if it turns out to be false, how can I do better?

My attempt:
a. Let $A$ such that $|A|=ℵ_{0}$. Note that as $A$ is infinite, there exists a bijection from $A$ to a strict subset $A'$ of itself. Also note, that $|A'|=ℵ_{0}$ and that $A=$($A$ \ $A'$)$∪A'$. As A is infinite, ($A$ \ $A'$) is also infinite, therefore setting $B=A'$ and $C=$($A$ \ $A'$) gets us our result.

b. identical.

Comment: I have made a minor change, which is what I think you did intend. Revert it if that's not the case.

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect between "for every infinite set" in the question title and a body that only asks for the cardinalities $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph$. I hope you're aware that there are other infinite cardinalities than those two.

Comment: Hint: every ordinal is either even or odd, as it can be written uniquely as the ordinal sum of a limit ordinal and an integer. Prove that if you can’t assume it.

Comment: My takeaway from the link you cite: unsubscripted aleph is nonstandard notation for size of continuum and should be defined (you didn’t) if you want to use it, which you shouldn’t.

Comment: @Troposphere More precisely, not you but OP used this notation but didn't define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael Barz has shown a counterexample to your assertion that $A\setminus A'$ must be infinite. Here's a hint for "how can I do better?":

(a) Since $|A|=\aleph_0$ by assumption, you know that there is a bijection $f:\mathbb N\to A$. Therefore if you find a solution for $A=\mathbb N$, you can transfer that solution to any *other* $A$ simply by applying that bijection to each of the two subsets you break $\mathbb N$ into.

In mathematical jargon, this reasoning is usually expressed by saying "without loss of generality we can assume $A=\mathbb N$". (When used alone, this phrasing leaves it to the reader to imagine how you generalize a solution for $\mathbb N$ to a solution for a generic $A$, so in a classroom setting, you'll need also to explain how that works).

Now, can you find two sets $B, C\subseteq \mathbb N$ such that each of them is countably infinite and $\mathbb N$ is their disjoint union?

(b) Since $|A|=\aleph$, without loss of generality we can assume $A=\mathbb R$ ...

Comment: So whenever I have an infinite set with cardinality א, since there exsists a bijection f:N->A, I can, for example, claim that I can split that fucntion f into f':N_even->A, f'':N_odd->A and both image of f' and image of f'' are infinite sets that share no elements?

Comment: There is NO cariinal named $\aleph$, which is a class function bijecting ordinals and infinite cardinals. So b) perhaps should be $\aleph_{\alpha}$, meaning “any infinite cardinal. Your answer to b) is wrong even if it said $\aleph_1$: you seem to assume the Continuum Hypothesis is true. In fact ZFC proves that the size of $\mathbb{R}$ is an aleph, but cannot prove which one it is.

Comment: @BrianO: $\aleph$ without any subscript is sometimes used to denote the cardinality of the continuum, that is, the cardinal more commonly known as $\mathfrak c$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$ or $\beth_1$. This usage appears to be rare -- in fact I cannot offhand find any online reference to it. However, it's the only way I can think of for the assumption $|A|=\aleph$ the OP quotes to make sense.

Comment: [Here is one question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9475/symbol-for-the-cardinality-of-the-continuum) that mentions the notation $\aleph$ for $2^{\aleph_0}$, just to show I didn't just dream it up myself.

Comment: Sorry I but I don't quiet get it. :( In my original response I meant א0, which we were taught is the cardinality of the naturals. Also, as Set Theory was just a fraction of our Logic&SetTheory course we only had about a month worth of material to cover, so in our course we've learned that the cardinality of the naturals is א0 and of the reals is א, any cardinality larger than those two we denotes as 2^א etc..

Comment: But My question still stands. Since A is of cardinality א0 (or א) there exists a bijection from N->A, and I can claim that the image of the odd numbers and the image of the even numbers of my function are two sets that their union gives us A and their intersection is empty? and in case it's of cardinality א I can say there exists a bijection R->A

Comment: and the image of (0,1) and the image of R/(0,1) will give me the desired result?

Comment: @MathCurious: Yes, you proposal of odd/even numbers for $\mathbb N$ and $(0,1)$ vs everything else for $\mathbb R$ will work, so I'd say you have a solution there.

Comment: @MathCurious: More notation: Note that the symbol for $|\mathbb N|$ is $\aleph_0$, not $0_\aleph$. The latter means nothing at all, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @MathCurious: When you write "any cardinality larger than those two" it sounds vaguely like your course has left you with the impression that there is no cardinality strictly _between_ $|\mathbb N|$ and $|\mathbb R|$. The question whether that is true is known as the _continuum hypothesis_ and was arguably the most famous open problem in set theory for most of its history, until it was eventually shown that standard set theory _can neither prove nor disprove_ that such intermediate cardinalities exist. (...)

Comment: (...) Modern set theory generally prefers to speak about things under a working assumption that sets with intermediate cardinalities are "probably out there somewhere", though we know we can _depend_ on them being there. Unfortunately there are many short introductory texts that find it easier to avoid mentioning the possibility at all, leading to misconceptions -- especially since they still feel obliged to explain what the $0$ in $\aleph_0$ is for, so students will know that $\aleph_1$ is "the next larger cardinality", without being told very loudly that this is not necessarily $|\Bbb R|$.

Comment: Yes they have mentioned what you're saying, but we didn't really dwell into it. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Troposphere I deleted my last comment, I misread (mis-saw?) yours.

Answer (score 4):

This is very wrong. Not every subset of an infinite set is infinite. For instance, if $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $A' = \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\},$ then $A\setminus A' = \{0\}$ is not infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a bijection $f$ from $A \times \{0,1\}$ to $A$ and define $B$ and $C$ to be $f(A \times \{0\})$ and $f(A \times \{1\})$ respectively. Then, $B$ and $C$ are two complementary subsets of $A$ with the same cardinality as $A$.

Comment: The fact that you _can_ pick a bijection between $A$ and $A\times\{0,1\}$ is essentially what the exercise asks for a proof of in the first place ...

Comment: @Troposphere Agreed; this is begging the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to prove this for sets $A$ that are infinite cardinals. We'll use the following

**Proposition**: Every ordinal can be written uniquely as the ordinal sum of: a limit ordinal or $0$, and an integer.

Thus "the integer part of an ordinal" $\mathsf{int}(\alpha)$ is well-defined, and we can call an ordinal *even* or *odd* according as its integer part is even or odd. Given an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, let $B = \{\alpha < \kappa \,|\, \alpha$ is even$\}$, $C = \{\alpha < \kappa \,|\, \alpha$ is odd$\}$. Clearly these are disjoint subsets of $\kappa$, and each is of size $\kappa$ as witnessed by these bijections:

$$\alpha \mapsto \alpha + \mathsf{int}(\alpha) \colon \kappa\to B$$
and
$$\alpha \mapsto \alpha + \mathsf{int}(\alpha) + 1 \colon 
\kappa\to C.$$

---

Proof of Proposition:

This is obvious for finite ordinals ($n = 0 + n$), so let $\alpha$ be infinite.

Let $\lambda = \mathsf{sup} \,\{ \gamma \,|\, \gamma < \alpha \,\text{and}\, \gamma \,\text{is a limit ordinal}\}$. Then $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal and $\lambda \le \alpha$. If $\lambda = \alpha$ then $\alpha = \lambda + 0$. Otherwise, $\lambda < \alpha$, so let $\beta = $ the ordertype of the closed-open ordinal interval $[\lambda, \alpha)$. Then $\alpha = \lambda + \beta$. If $\beta \ge \omega$, then $\beta = \omega + \delta$ for some $\delta$, so $\alpha = \lambda + \omega + \delta$; however, this is impossible, because then $\lambda +\omega$ is a limit ordinal $\le\alpha$ that's greater than $\lambda$, but $\lambda$ is the largest limit $\le \alpha$. So $\beta$ must be an integer.

Uniqueness of the $\lambda + n$ decomposition: left as an easy exercise.